# Make this query to more simple

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query that will connect to my database.
I encountered it's too slow to load the data that i want.

```
SELECT
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS dt_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'DT'),0) AS dt_amounts,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS rt_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'RT'),0) AS rt_amounts,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS it_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'IT'),0) AS it_amounts,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS lr_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'LR'),0) AS lr_amounts,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS ir_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'IR'),0) AS ir_amounts,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.due_to_office) AS v_amount FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.so_category = 'V'),0) AS v_amounts;
```

Comment: Skip the subqueries, use case expressions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.so_category, SUM(c.due_to_office) AS dt_amount 
FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b, sales_entry c 
WHERE a.ses_id = c.ses_id AND a.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND a.`status` = 'AUDITED' AND a.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP BY b.so_category
HAVING b.so_category in ('DT', 'RT', 'IT', 'LR', 'IR', 'V')
```

will yield rows with so_category and the sum for you. If you want to have a single row, then wrap a select arounc the select above and use case when.

EDIT

Of course you can join the tables, which would be an improvement.

Comment: how could i display the so_category that has null value or 0;

Comment: @ArnieMallari In the HAVING you need to allow null for so_category, but since null is not equal to null (it's strange, I know, but it is what it is) you need to allow it separately, like HAVING b.so_category in ('DT', 'RT', 'IT', 'LR', 'IR', 'V') or (b.so_category is null). In the selection if you would like to use some defaults, you can use the IFNULL function for that purpose, you have examples for that in the code you have given in the question.

Comment: @ArnieMallari if you have a situation where there are some categories in b, which are not associated to any records in a or c, then the query above filters them out. In that case you would need to transform the query above from Descartes mutiplications into a selection from b and left joining a and c to it. That would yield even those records in b which have no associated records in a or c and to improve the way you gather the values you can use the IFNULL function.

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  `JOIN` has been part of SQL for well over two decades.  It is time to learn the language correctly.

I suspect that conditional aggregation will help with your problem:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'DT' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS dt_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'RT' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS rt_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'IT' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS it_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'LR' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS ir_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'IR' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS ir_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.so_category = 'V' THEN c.due_to_office ELSE 0 END) AS v_amount  
FROM sales_entry_summary ses JOIN
     sales_entry se
     ON ses.ses_id = se.ses_id JOIN
     sales_products sp
     ON ses.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE ses.sales_date = '2019-01-01' AND
      ses.status = 'AUDITED';
```

For additional performance you want an index on `sales_entry_summary(sales_date, status)`.